# Core Data Fault

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode, core-data

I implemented core data in my app. 
I try to fetch the data from coreData when network is reachable in appDelegate.
The fetch data are saved in array & pass this into first view controller.

When I try to get any data from array in view controller then app crashes due to fault occurred & id is nil.

`(entity: Person; id: 0xd000000000180000 <x-coredata://0A2E929E-B3CF-4150-BC81-E7E3D54580BF/Person/p6> ; data: <fault>)`

**Sometimes error is**

```
error: use of undeclared type 'demo'
$__lldb__DumpForDebugger(Swift.UnsafePointer<demo.Person>(bitPattern: 0x112dc2af0).memory)
                                             ^~~~~~~
/var/folders/vp/9hmnqkhn79n455bp9knwrg_00000gn/T/lldb/574/expr6.swift:1:45: note: while parsing this '<' as a type parameter bracket
$__lldb__DumpForDebugger(Swift.UnsafePointer<demo.Person>(bitPattern: 0x112dc2af0).memory)
                                            ^
```

If I try to fetch data in ViewController instead of AppDelegate then it works fine.

**Please let me know how can I solve this**

**Thank you**

Comment: please add your code for getting data

Answer (score -2):

Core Data throws core data fault due to unnecessary fetching of records from data e.g. unwanted load of relationships. Earlier 9.0 core data fault was an exception but in iOS 9 we get an encrypted message. For more information please follow below tutorial

[CoreData Fault](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/what-is-a-core-data-fault--cms-25157)

They have given a great example & scenario for Core Data fault.